# how to use `prompt` on Node.js REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using `node` as a JavaScript REPL. Is it possible to use `prompt` as in the example below?

```
function foo() {
    var i = prompt("enter value for i: ");
    console.log('i is now: '+i);
}

foo();
```

When I run the above code (loading it from file `j.js`), I get:

```
$ node
> .load j.js
>     function foo() {
...         var i = prompt("enter value for i: ");
...         console.log('i is now: '+i);
...     }
undefined
>     
undefined
>     foo();
ReferenceError: prompt is not defined
    at foo (repl:2:9)
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:203:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:532:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:815:20)
```

... failing a solution to the above problem, is that some other tool (console-based, not browser-based) I can use as a JavaScript REPL?

Answer (score 1):

So you can read stdio from the script you're running, which is the main way to do it from the console.  There's a number of modules for making things interactive, but the straight node core way to do it is with readline:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What do you think of node.js? ", function(answer) {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log("Thank you for your valuable feedback:", answer);

  rl.close();
});
```

Comment: With the provided script, the `node` console exits after user provides the input and printing `Thank you...`. If I comment out the `rl.close()` line it doesn't exit but it's not useful as a REPL any more as it keeps echoing whatever I type in. I am using `node` for experimentation / prototyping as a REPL in case I haven't made that clear.

Answer (score -1):

Prompt is a statement and you're using it as an object. Instead of doing this:

```
    var i = prompt("enter value for i: ");
```

You should do this:

```
     prompt("enter value for i: ");
```

Comment: This is simply incorrect. 1) Why would you have a prompt that does not assign a value to a variable and 2) in REPL prompt is not defined.